# Getting error while installing tensorflow on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Hi I am trying to install tensorflow with Anaconda . I am following the instruction from the official site:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

`conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5`

`activate tensorflow`

`(tensorflow) C:\Users\guar8001>pip install tensorflow`

I am getting the following error:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\guar8001>pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached tensorflow-1.7.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\shutil.py", line 391, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.rmdir(path)
OSError: [WinError 145] The directory is not empty: 'C:\\Users\\guar8001\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fkfkeii_\\tensorflow\\tensorflow-1.7.0.data\\purelib\\tensorflow\\python'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 388, in run
    wheel_cache.cleanup()
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 58, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 81, in cleanup
    rmtree(self.path)
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 108, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\shutil.py", line 494, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\shutil.py", line 393, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\users\guar8001\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 120, in rmtree_errorhandler
    func(path)
OSError: [WinError 145] The directory is not empty: 'C:\\Users\\guar8001\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fkfkeii_\\tensorflow\\tensorflow-1.7.0.data\\purelib\\tensorflow\\python'
```

How can I install tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a couple of scenarios:

1.Having the build directory open in a window

2.Anti-virus

Of these, two  second is temporary and waiting will likely resolve the issue. The first(open in a window) I suspect is an instance of the more general "something is using the directory as the cwd" which won't go away until that process completes (and it can happen that a persistent background process ends up with the directory as cwd, meaning it won't go away till a reboot).